# React Native text script parsing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to dynamically inject react native script into code.

I have dynamically generated script like:

```
<Text><Text styles={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Two Color Options</Text></Text><Text> <Text><Text styles={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Stone Grey</Text>- Great for new...  </Text>
```

and need to show it like a Text components with styles in react-native application.

I tried react-jsx-parser but it doesn't work as expected.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add dynamic text in the string provided as children to the `<Text>` component.
For example:

```
const dynamicText = 'option1'

return (
   <>
      <Text styles={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Two Color Options</Text>
      <Text>{dynamicText}</Text>
   </>
)
```

If `dynamicText` can be undefined, you could use the following syntax

```
const dynamicText = 'option1'

return (
   <>
      <Text styles={{ fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Two Color Options</Text>
      {!!dynamicText && <Text>{dynamicText}</Text>}
   </>
)
```

Here the text will only show if dynamicText is evaluated to true. So it is not undefined, null or '' (empty string).

The `!!` syntax converts the value to a boolean. Without it, '' would return falsy and would be added to the component. This gives an error because React Native does not allow string not rendered inside a `<Text>` component.